# Will I always be able to get a zero-interest credit card?

Tags: credit-card, credit

(Note this question presupposes that my credit score will always be high enough to qualify for a 0% interest card).

I've taken to using the introductory 0% interest rates on credit cards to my advantage - finding them to be a nice place to park large purchases, especially those made with shops and service-providers that don't normally offer financing themselves. The 0% period is usually 12 months, but some are 15 or 21 months.

For the past 3 years I've obtained a number of 0% interest cards from different banks, especially store-cards like Amazon, Macys, Lovesac, and Apple (an Apple-branded card from BarclayCardUS). Amazon and Lovesac are both rebranded Synchrony cards, and Macys is "DSNB" - their own in-house financing company. I also have 0% Citi card which has a generous 21 month period.

You might notice that these are all from different banks - supposing I get a Bank-of-America 0% card this year, and a WellsFargo card the following year - after a few more years I will have a card from every major bank in the US.

I'm assuming I can continue to do this provided a new 0% credit card offer comes along at least once a year, but eventually I'll need a second 0% card from a bank I already have one from.

...will banks eventually stop issuing 0% cards to me because I already have one, even if it's a different card range (e.g. Citi Simplicity vs Citi Diamond Preferred)?

(Note that I do pay at least the minimum payment every month and always pay-off the balance entirely at least a month before the 0% period ends).

Comment: Some banks have rules where you can't qualify for the same reward/bonus more than once on a particular product (credit card).

Comment: Assuming that you'll *always* be able to get some reward is... head scratching.

Comment: It might be time to consider paying your debts, and living within your means.  This is not sustainable.

Comment: @Ben Miller: Why not?  Assume you get credit card #1 with 0% interest for a year.  You put your spending on the card, and invest the money.  At the end of the period, you pay it off just before incurring interest, with the money you've invested.  With reasonable luck, you have a profit, too.  Then in year 2, you do the same thing with a second card, and so on for as long as you can get cards.  You're living within your means, but have a 'float' of 1/2 your annual spending invested.  Plus many of the cards offer various signup bonuses; my most recent one had $100 at REI.

Comment: @jamesqf Correct, yes, that's what I do.

Comment: Can you pay off all your debt immediately if you are unable to get a new 0% card? If not, you are potentially headed for trouble. If you can, why are you worried about not being able to obtain a 0% card in the future?

Comment: @BenMiller Yes, I can - it just means having to liquidate some of my investment funds. Why am I worried? I'm not terribly worried - but I'd rather be making 7% than nothing :)

Answer (score 7):

No.  There is no guarantee that credit card issuing banks will always use 0% introductory rates to entice anyone.

Comment: But what about existing customers?

Comment: @Dai oh right, them either, edited

Comment: @Dai, as a random data point, when I did this several decades ago, it lasted 3 years before I stopped getting interesting offers.  All of the cards were from different banks--I did not get any duplicate offers within that period.  ymmv.

Comment: I've been doing it for about 8-9 years now, and still get offers - some from the companies I already have cards with :-)

Comment: @jamesqf, that's not a guarantee that companies will always offer this in to the future.  I've also gotten loads of 0% offers through the years.

Comment: @quid: Sure, the only reason they can offer 0% interest now is that general interest rates are low.  If they go up significantly - more than the expected profit from the new card users the offers attract - they'll stop,

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the comments, and your replies it seems that your mind is made up: "You will always be able to obtain 0% credit, and nothing bad will ever happen".

Credit cards that offer 0% on balance transfers are very rare.  Most have a transfer fee of some kind, which acts like an interest rate.  This is a change that probably happened 10 years ago without much fanfare.  From this you can draw a lesson: what changes will come in the future?

This site and others a full of "tales of woe" where people were playing musical chairs with credit, and when the music stopped, there was no chairs in sight.  Job loss, medical expenses, unexpected taxes, natural disasters can all effect one's ability to make payments on time and happen.  Once payments start being missed or are late, things tend to avalanche from there.  It has happened to me, and loved ones. The pain and suffering is not worth it.  Get out of debt.

You claim that you are investing the money instead of paying on the debt, and you are making the delta between your prevailing investment rate 7%.  Did you include the balance transfer fee in your calculations?

First off your investments could lose money.  While 2015 was mostly flat, we have not had a correction in a long time.  Some say we are long overdue. 
 Secondly, how much money are we really talking about here?  Say there is not a balance transfer fee, you could be guaranteed 7%, and you are floating $10K.  Congratulations in this mythical scenario you just made $700.

If $700 changes your life dramatically perhaps it is time for a second job.  This way you can earn that every two weeks (working part time) rather than every year.  Now that will really change your life.  By applying this amount of mental energy to make $700, what opportunities are you missing?

Pay off the debt, you will be much better off in the long run.

Comment: For me, and I think for the OP, there are no balance transfers (except once, when Chase Slate did offer a 0% transfer a few years ago).  And no, $700 or whatever doesn't change my life dramatically, as I make more than I spend anyway :-)  (A second job would change my life, by reducing my free time.)  It's just money for nothing, like picking up that dollar bill blowing down the sidewalk.

Comment: @jamesqf there is no risk for picking a dollar off the side walk.  By rolling transfers one is assuming a lot of risk.  Big difference.  I'll ebay/recycle junk I find, but rolling transfers is not worth it.

Comment: Once again, there are no balance transfers (other than that one 0% one).  So explain exactly where the risk is, when the outstanding balance is never more than a couple of percent of my investment holdings.  Worst possible case I can see is that I might have to sell a few shares at a loss.